# C rand() function is not generating random numbers

Tags: c, random, numbers

I am new in programming. I need something which can generate random number with C. I found "rand()". But it is not generating random values. Please check the following simple code.

The following code gives

```
roll the first dice : 6
roll the second dice : 6
roll the third dice : 5
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{

  int dice1,dice2,dice3,total1,total2;
  char prediction[10];

int dice_generator()
{
  dice1= (rand()%6)+1;
  printf("roll the first dice: %d \n", dice1);
  dice2= (rand()%6)+1;
  printf("roll the second dice: %d \n", dice2);
  dice3= (rand()%6)+1;
  printf("roll the third dice: %d \n", dice3);

  return 0;
}

  dice_generator();
  total1 = dice1+dice2+dice3;
  printf("final value is = %d\n",total1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user4397355: Why is your `dice_generator()` defined inside `main()`???

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to better understand how to ask questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That is no valid C code. C does not allow to define a function inside a _block_. This is one of the less useful gcc extensions.

Comment: Thanks @MagnusKarlsson i will read those terms for how to ask..

Comment: @olaf  may be fundamentally your are right but my compiler is not giving any error for this.

Comment: @user4397355: That is nothing "fundamentally". Enable warnings and use `-std=c99` or c11. You should really stick to ste stnadard, expecially as there is noting gained here in not conforming. Oh: which compiler is that actually? The options above are for gcc (not sure about clang). Read @Ant's answer, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to "seed" the random number generator.
Try calling

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

once at the top of your program.

(There are better ways, but this should get you started.)

Comment: Even if using `srand` instead of a serious RNG, I would still seed from `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: @o11c: Oh, so would I.  But the OP said he was "new in programming", so finding a better seed will be a good exercise for another day.

Comment: Thanks Steve.. I put srand(time(NULL)); and now its generating different numbers.

Comment: If you find an answer helpful, you should accept the best answer. It's part of the flow of the website and lets future viewers know how to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, C language does not support nested functions. It is illegal to define `dice_generator()` inside the definition of `main()` as in your code. Your compiler might support this, but in any case this is not C.

Secondly, `rand()` does not generate random numbers. `rand()` produces a seemingly "erratic" but perfectly deterministic sequence of integers, which begins at some initial number and always follows the same path. All you can do is make `rand()` start its sequence from a different "seed" number by calling `srand` with a new seed as an argument.

By default `rand()` is required to work as if you called `srand(1)` in order to seed the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

here is the code, after being corrected so the sub function dice_generator()

is properly separated, rather than buried in main().
(in C, nested functions are not allowed)

the rand() function is properly initialized via the srand() function.

unused variables ( total2 and prediction[] ) are commented out

(another excellent reason to only place one variable declaration per line)

Strongly suggest enabling all the warnings when compiling,

so your compiler can tell you about problems in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// prototypes
int dice_generator( void );

 // global data
 int dice1;
 int dice2;
 int dice3;
 int total1;
 //int total2;
 //char prediction[10];

int main( void )
{

  srand(time( NULL ));
  dice_generator();
  total1 = dice1+dice2+dice3;
  printf("final value is = %d\n",total1);
  return 0;
} // end function: main


int dice_generator()
{
  dice1= (rand()%6)+1;
  printf("roll the first dice: %d \n", dice1);
  dice2= (rand()%6)+1;
  printf("roll the second dice: %d \n", dice2);
  dice3= (rand()%6)+1;
  printf("roll the third dice: %d \n", dice3);

  return 0;
} // end function: dice_generator
```

Comment: for gcc, at a minimum, use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic std=c99'  so the compiler can tell you about problems (that you need to fix)

Comment: yes, it shows such messages in warning section.